# Unkown Class error trying to implement dependency injection

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection

I'm using generics to get my code reusable and to utilize dependency injection.

I have two Interfaces: DataParserImplementation and ObjectImplementation. I have  classes that implement each: SalesRepbyId implements DataParserImpl (it parses the data into objects and puts those objects into collections). SalesRep implements Objectimpl (It is the object for a specific dataset).

I'm trying to get it so that I can select which kind of Objectimpl I use in my SalesRepbyId class so I can remove the coupling.

I know there is something called reflection that I've been told is the method I need to use. I also have heard about a "Factory Pattern" and a "Properties file" that allows me to do what I want to do. A lot of this is very confusing so please explain it like I'm five.

Here is the code with where it stops working:

EDIT: Revisions based on comments: I want to specify the type of DataObject (D) my class uses by passing it through the constructor via a common interface and using generic types. When I try and use it instead of a concrete implementing class, I get the error. I can't find anything about this error.

```
   public class SalesRepbyId<D extends ObjectImplementation> implements DataParserImplementation<Map<String,D>> {
private FileParserImplementation<ArrayList<String[]>> FileParser;
private D dataObject;

public SalesRepbyId(FileParserImplementation<ArrayList<String[]>> FileParser,D d){
    this.FileParser = FileParser;
    this.dataObject = d;
}
@Override
public Map<String, D> Parse() {

    try{
        //reads the file and returns an array of string arrays
        ArrayList<String[]> Salesrep_contactlist =  FileParser.ReadFile;
        //here it still says "Unknown Class." that's the problem
        Map<String, dataObject> SalesrepByIdMap = new HashMap<>();
  //I want to be able to put in any class that implements 
  //dataObject into this class and have it run the same way.
```

Comment: `here when I try to say that my DataObject is a Salesrep Object it doesn't recognize the Sales_Rep variable as a Salesrep instance` - You are ***not*** saying that. You are assigning `DataObject`'s class to an object of type `Class` called `Sales_Rep`.

Comment: Ok so is the fix just to say: Salesrep rep = DataObject.getClass(); Edit no that didn't work

Comment: You should first learn the naming conventions. You have a type variable `DataObject` in your class declaration and an instance field named `DataObject` in your class. When following the convention to use lowercase letters for variables, you wouldn’t confuse these two. Then, using the type variable for declaring the field, i.e. `DataObject dataObject;` instead of `ObjectImplementation DataObject;`, makes that nonsensical type cast obsolete. By the way, the other type cast is wrong too. It is impossible for `FileParser` to be an `ArrayList<String[]>`.

Comment: Ok so I did what Holger suggested. Casted dataObject to Salesrep and it still didn't recognize it as a Salesrep.

Comment: I never said that. You should stop mindlessly casting objects. There is no class `Salesrep` in your code, so why do you try to cast to it? You have a *type variable* named `DataObject` in your class declaration, that is `public class SalesRepbyId<DataObject extends ObjectImplementation> …`. You are not using it. And, just to make that sure, by using it, I don’t mean using it in type cast. Declare your variable using the right type in the first place.

Comment: Wait. I'm confusing myself: I want to be able to specify that my SalesrepbyIdMap uses a DataObject class rather than only allowing it to use a Salesrep. I'm not trying to make a Salesrep instance I'm trying to tell the map to use a class that's passed in via the constructor (thus removing the dependency)

Comment: Another (not as well documented) convention is to use a single uppercase letter for a generic type.  As in, `List<T>`.  Don’t try to make your generic arguments look like classes.  It may seem clever, but really, it only makes things more confusing.  If you’re worried a single letter will be unclear, document it in the method’s javadoc, for example `@param <D> The specific type of data object.`

Comment: EDIT: ok I've figured out that I want to use my dataObject class field as the type that my map and other methods take in. for some reason it won't let me saying its unknown class.                                                                                      EDIT2: thanks for that VGR it made it a lot cleaner

Comment: Now, you surely want to use `Map<String, D> salesrepByIdMap` instead of `Map<String, dataObject> SalesrepByIdMap`. Then you have a map that allows putting `dataObject` as a value or querying a value that you can assign to `dataObject`. You still have to clean up that `FileParser` thing. Its type is `FileParserImplementation<ArrayList<String[]>>`, which is very unlikely an instance of `ArrayList<String[]>` at the same time, so don’t cast it. Perhaps, `FileParserImplementation` has a method which *returns* an `ArrayList<String[]>` instead?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Isn't dataObject of type D as it is currently set up? Also fileparser takes in a generic type which I'm casting to ArrayList<String[]> for this specific class that uses it. I think the cast is unchecked though. EDIT: wait I think I understand kinda what youre talking about with the fileparser thing. It is supposed to return a String array not necessarily be a type. I think I mgihtve confused the parameter for a return type or something. How do I fix that?

Comment: Holger you were right about the fileparser. I wanted to call the method to return an Arraylist of string arrays rather than cast the object. Thanks for that. I'm just stuck on how to make this code such that I can pass anything that implements "D" into the class. I'm clearly missing some important concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Summary of what I did

I Implemented the `Factory` Design pattern and created a `properties` file which allowed me to reflect in the class I wanted instead of trying to use a generic `DataObject` (or `D`) type.

## Details of Solution

Reflecting the class using the properties file `"config.properties"` and then casting it to type `Objectimplementation` allowed me to use any class that implemented that interface (and was implemented in the `Factory` and set in the `properties` file). I then refactored all instances of `D` to type `ObjectImplementation` since the parent interface is the layer of abstraction needed here rather than a generic concrete class.

## Why it didn't work the way I tried it in the question

the reason the generic `D` type doesn't work with reflection is because reflection uses a concrete classtype determined at runtime and the generic `D` type is specified before runtime. Thus I was trying to reflect in the classtype and its methods/instances without properly using reflection and the code was telling me that the classtype was unknown at the time I needed it.

## Code example to compare to the Question code

Example of the working code:

```
public class SalesRepbyId implements 
DataParserImplementation<Map<String,ObjectImplementation>> {
    private FileParserImplementation<ArrayList<String[]>> FileParser;
    //the Factory class that creates instances of the reflected class I wanted
    private ObjectFactory Factory = new ObjectFactory();

    public Map<String, ObjectImplementation> Parse() {
        //the proeprties object which then loads properties from a file and reflects the classtype I want
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        //loading in the classtype and casting it to the subclass of ObjectImplementation that it actually is
        prop.load(SalesRepbyId.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        Class<? extends ObjectImplementation> Classtouse = Class.forName(prop.getProperty("ObjectImplementation")).asSubclass(ObjectImplementation.class);
        //construct instances of 'Classtouse' and parse the data into these dynamically typed objects
        //return the map that holds these objects
        }
```